# Invariant tag error including stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

No clue what is wrong with this code, I can't call the component.

```
const radarChart = ({data}) => (
    <h1>x</h1>
)

export default radarChart
```

See here https://codesandbox.io/s/x3n3xnv4oz

Comment: You need to import React first: `import React from 'react'`

Comment: @ArmanCharan tried that, doesn't work either

Comment: You forgot the `.js` suffix for your `radarChart` file: `radarChart.js`